# filter data.frame in R according to variable values and an external list

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 5 variable and 2k rows. I need to filter this data.frame in R keeping all the rows in which BOTH var2 and var1 are in a specific list (fle: `list.txt`). If both var 1 and var 2 or one of the two are not in the list, the row should be deleted.

Example:

```
> df(head)
             Var2       Var1    GS    Info_region.x    Info_region.y
    27475 1wd2_A_001 2ct7_A_002 0.675 RNF31_region_010 ARIH1_region_008
    27521 1wd2_A_001 2ct7_A_001 0.713 RNF31_region_005 ARIH1_region_008
    37576 2crc_A_001 1wd2_A_001 0.709 ARIH1_region_008 RBCK1_region_002
    37688 2crc_A_001 2ct7_A_002 0.793 RNF31_region_010 RBCK1_region_002
    37701 2crc_A_001 2ct7_A_001 0.834 RNF31_region_005 RBCK1_region_002
    42636 2ct7_A_002 2ct7_A_001 0.826 RNF31_region_005 RNF31_region_010


list.txt:
1wd2_A_001
2ct7_A_001
2crc_A_001


output:
     Var2       Var1    GS    Info_region.x    Info_region.y
    27521 1wd2_A_001 2ct7_A_001 0.713 RNF31_region_005 ARIH1_region_008
    37576 2crc_A_001 1wd2_A_001 0.709 ARIH1_region_008 RBCK1_region_002
    37701 2crc_A_001 2ct7_A_001 0.834 RNF31_region_005 RBCK1_region_002
```

Could someone suggest a script in R to do this please? Thank you!

Comment: Please share a reproducible piece of your data so that others can use it in order to help you.

Comment: The entered data should be enough to test the script, is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
list <- read_csv("list.txt", col_names = FALSE)

df %>% filter(var1 %in% list$X1 & var2 %in% list$X1)
```

Comment: I believe the OP meant "filter". That's a function in the tidyverse package, but in this case you can substitute base R's "subset" function. It has the exact same syntax for this use case, so just change the name.

Comment: Errore: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x oggetto "var1" non trovato
i Input `..1` is `var1 %in% list$V1 & var2 %in% list$V1`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. What's the problem?

Comment: yep. Thx... I just correct fiter to filter.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Var1  %in% list.txt & Var2  %in% list.txt)
        Var1       Var2
1 2ct7_A_001 2crc_A_001
2 1wd2_A_001 1wd2_A_001
```

Data:

```
list.txt <- c("1wd2_A_001","2ct7_A_001","2crc_A_001")

df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c("1wd2_A_001", "somethingelse", "2ct7_A_001", "1wd2_A_001"),
  Var2 = c("otherstuff", "something", "2crc_A_001", "1wd2_A_001")
)
```